# What is the difference between a "meta model" and "design patterns"?

Tags: design-patterns

Where is the difference between a "meta model" and "design patterns"?

If you take, for example, Fowlers "Identity Field" from his book "Patterns Of Enterprise Application Architecture": Why is this a pattern and not a meta model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Design Pattern**: It is a "good practice". It can be considered as a possible solution for a problem that may ofter occur. The solution usually comes from the experience.  Examples are [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [Identify Field](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityField.html).

**Metamodel**: It can be considered as a set of rules, constraints and constructs that allow to model a problem.
As an example you can consider a map.

[image]

A map allows to model the reality, so a map can be considered the model. The metamodel of a map is the legend: the constructs that you need to use in order to represent borders, rivers, lakes,...

In your case *Identify Field* is just a good practice that you can decide to follow or not. It's not a constraint/rule.

Comment: Thanks! Is this also stated somewhere in literature, so that I can cite it?